# How do I change the parent class in ANTLR-3?

Tags: inheritance, antlr, antlr3

By default, a parser generated using ANTLR-3 extends from org.antlr.runtime.Parser. How do I have it extend my custom class instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by using the `superClass` option in your grammar:

```
grammar G;

options {
  superClass = YourCustomClass;
}

parse
  :  ...
  ;
```

which will generate:

```
public class GParser extends YourCustomClass {

    // ...

}
```